# How to use object short hand with functions not declared in the object

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6

Say I'm using a revealing module pattern and have nested functions like:

```
function outer () {
    function a () {}
    function b () {}
    function c () {}
}
```

can i reveal those functions with object shorthand like:

`return { a, b, c };`

or do i need to bind them to a variable like:

```
var a = function a () {};
var b = function b () {};
```

Comment: Except for _the object shorthand_, ES6 is not needed.

Comment: I mean, I added the tag specifically because object shorthand was a part of es6.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> can i reveal those functions with object shorthand like:
>
> ```
> return { a, b, c };
> ```

Yes. Each function declaration like the ones in your question creates a binding of an identifier (the function name) to a value (the function object) in the current [lexical environment object](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-lexical-environments); these bindings are just like the bindings created by variables, and can be used with the new ES2015 shorthand object notation.

Example (you'll need to use a browser that supports ES2015's shorthand notation; any recent Chrome or Firefox does):

```js
function outer () {
    function a () { console.log("a"); }
    function b () { console.log("b"); }
    function c () { console.log("c"); }
    return {a, b, c};
}
const o = outer();
o.a(); // "a"
```

Comment: Even you can do it in shortest way: `function outer(){ return { a(){console.log('a'); }, b(){...}, c(){...} } }`

Comment: @JoseHermosillaRodrigo: Yes, of course; but I read the question as being specifically about the shorthand notation and function declarations.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to test it : https://jsfiddle.net/cuvvn2sw/1/

So yes this will work

(code :

```
function outer () {
    function a () {
    alert('a');
    }
    function b () {
    alert('b');}
    function c () {
    alert('c');}

    return {a,b,c};
}

var fcts = outer();

fcts.a();
fcts.b();
fcts.c();
```

Comment: Yes, but testing it only tells you it works in the implementations you tested it in, not whether it *should* work or what the underlying mechanisms at work are.